# Почему strtotime некорректно определяет номер недели?

Tags: php

Вот код

```
$timestamp = strtotime('01.02.2021 00:00');
echo $week = date('W', $timestamp); //05
$timestamp = strtotime('01.01.2021 00:00');
echo $week = date('W', $timestamp); // 53
```

Как вы видите 01.02.2021 это пятая неделя. Верно.

Но 01.01.2021 это 53 неделя? По логике первая.

Почему strtotime некорректно определяет номер недели?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Номер недели вам выдает не `strtotime`, а `date`, преобразуя текстовую переменную в дату

`W` - номер недели в году, в соответствии со стандартом [ISO 8601](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), по которому неделя начинается с понедельника, что можно также прочесть в [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.format.php):

[image]

1 января 2021 года является пятницей, а значит эта неделя принадлежит предыдущему году (20-му), являясь в нем 53-й неделей. Первая неделя 2021 года началась 3 января.